# Подскажите инструменты для кластеризации данных

Tags: c#, машинное-обучение, кластеризация

Если есть решения на C#, то было бы очень кстати, т.к. я пишу на C#.

У меня есть такая задача:
Есть около 10000 услуг (Название, описание + цена).
Мне нужно найти похожие между собой услуги по названию и сгруппировать их в одну услугу. 
Например: Шиномонтаж, Услуга Шиномонтажа, Шиномонтаж межсезонный, Замена резины...

В идеале, я бы хотел получить просто Шиномонтаж, а все остальное как синонимы.

Понимаю, что для этого нужно задействовать какой-нибудь ML и как-то обучить его. Я готов это сделать. Но я не очень понимаю (без соотвествующих знаний) с чего начать, какую библиотеку применить для подобных действий.
Т.к. услуги будут постепенно добавляться и они должны попадать в соотвествующую группу.

Или для того чтобы решить мою задачу нужно прочитать много книг по ML и пройти курсы?

Comment: Если это разовая задача, то это проще вручную сделать за пару часов. 10к записей таки это не очень много

Comment: Не совсем разовая. Данные в будущем будут добавляться.  Да и 10К записей просмотреть вручную это не пару часов. Надо не терять контекст существующих или недавно созданных групп.

Comment: @Cepega А точно нельзя обойтись обычным разбором на слова и удалением мусорных слов, например услуга? Я конечно не эксперт в ML, но имхо если первые 2 можно сгруппировать хоть как-то между собой так как имеют похожие слова, а 3 вообще не похож на остальные и я сомневаюсь, что ML его правильно классифицирует, а ведь в других услугах зоопарк синонимов может быть по солиднее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как по мне, МL тут вообще никаким боком.

Для начала надо просто иметь (составить) список синонимов. Да, самостоятельно составлять -  муторно и долго. Но без списка никакой ИИ никогда не сможет понять, что, например "парикмахерская", "цирюльня", "салон стрижки" и "барбершоп" -  это одно и то-же. Можно, конечно, городить огород и обучать какую-нибуть сетку это делать, но ведь сетку надо обучать, для этого надо им скормить учебный набор данных, объем работы по созданию которого будет превышать объем работы по ручной разметке.

Однако есть и "хорошая новость". На самом деле готовые словари синонимов существуют. Их можно найти в сети или купить, избежав изобретения велосипеда. Правда, придется поупражняться в анализе того, насколько конкретный словарь подходит именно для вашей тематики, но это, вполне "проходимая" задача.

Ну а далее - все более менее просто :-). Выполняем морфемный разбор. Имеются готовые библиотеки, не уверен, правда, что на С#. На Python -

https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/user/index.html

на Java -

https://nlpub.ru/Mystem

Таких библиотек достаточно много, ищите по ключевым словам "морфемный разбор" или "морфемный анализ".

Затем проводим замену по словарю синонимов и заменяем их на слово, выбранное в качестве основного для синонимической группы.

В общем, вполне себе достаточно строго и понятно алгоритмизуемая задача.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.